# Mapping JSON with Map and Normal Objects

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

I am getting following JSON

```
{  
   'routers':
      {  
         'external_gateway_info':{  },
         'description':'',
         'gw_port_id':'1f290c84-02fe-4bdb-a063-77a425cc10f5',
         'tenant_name':'lmco-test'
      },
     'tenants':{  
          '82d1df3fcfc14ac594c6f5c5b6dcad6a':'lmco-test',
          '6eb4b2dd40dc4d63a3c8a691c371dd06':'admin',
          '10b0726823784ceca219821d44a2b5d1':'ivs-perf',
          'VRRP_Service':'VRRP_Service',
          '8fb76703c3084308a01d113751560730':'service'
      }
}
```

Now routers is a simple object where I am mapping keys/values to my class Routers.java but tenants are a HashMap. 
I am unable to find a way where I can use a single mapper to map both routers and tenants to a single Object

My mapper

```
JSONObject jsonData = new JsonRepresentation(entity).getJsonObject();
RootModel rootModel = mapper.readValue(jsonData.toString(), RootModel.class);
```

Where Root.java snippet

```
public class RootModel {

    private Router routers;
    private Tenant tenants;


    public RootModel(@JsonP
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no cleaner way to use one Map for this kind of data. What I did, I used two different mappers to map routers and tenants.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Router** class would be like,

```
class Router {

    private String external_gateway_info;
    private String description;
    private String gw_port_id;
    private String tenant_name;

    public String getExternal_gateway_info() {
        return external_gateway_info;
    }

    public void setExternal_gateway_info(String external_gateway_info) {
        this.external_gateway_info = external_gateway_info;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getGw_port_id() {
        return gw_port_id;
    }

    public void setGw_port_id(String gw_port_id) {
        this.gw_port_id = gw_port_id;
    }

    public String getTenant_name() {
        return tenant_name;
    }

    public void setTenant_name(String tenant_name) {
        this.tenant_name = tenant_name;
    }

}
```

and your **RootModel** would be like,

```
class RootModel {

    private Router routers;
    private HashMap<String, String> tenants;

    public Router getRouters() {
        return routers;
    }

    public void setRouters(Router routers) {
        this.routers = routers;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getTenants() {
        return tenants;
    }

    public void setTenants(HashMap<String, String> tenants) {
        this.tenants = tenants;
    }

}
```

Just convert your tenants to HashMap and it will work fine. Hope this will help you.